# which way is better for performance for downloading image from url inside collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

which way is better for performance for downloading image from url inside collectionview ?

For example
Downloading image from server url, can be done in multiple ways, which way is better:
1) create global dispatch concurrent queue with qos = utility. And then just execute download code async way.

```
private func donwnloadwithGlobalQueue(at indexpath : IndexPath){
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async { [weak self] in
      guard let weakself = self else{
        return
      }
      let url = weakself.urls[indexpath.item]

      guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url),
        let image = UIImage(data: data) else{
          return
      }
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let cell = self?.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexpath) as? PhotoCell {
          cell.display(image: image)
        }
      }
    }

  }
```

2) using nsurlssion data task method.

```
private func downloadwithURLSession(at indexpath : IndexPath){
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urls[indexpath.row]) { [weak self]  (data, response, error) in
      guard let weakself = self,
      let data = data,
      let image = UIImage(data: data) else{
          return
      }

      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let cell = weakself.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexpath) as? PhotoCell {
          cell.display(image: image)
        }
      }
    }.resume()
  }
```

Comment: You can use `Kingfisher` library...which is developed in pure swift, easy to use and widely used by developers.

Comment: Did you measure it?

Comment: What were the results when you tested them?

Answer (score 1):

The download performance will be indistinguishable.

But, you should use `URLSession` (or a library like Kingfisher, which also uses `URLSession`) because (a) it gives you greater control over the connection; (b) if it fails, it gives you more diagnostic information; and (c) it offers cancelation capabilities. We often talk about “pros and cons” of different approaches, but in the case of `Data(contentsOf:)`, it’s only “cons”.

That having been said, there are five key ways we improve performance:

1. **Caches**

   Make sure that after your app downloads an image, that if that cell scrolls out of view and then back into view, that you don’t initiate a new network request. You just downloaded the asset, so you should use that. Sometimes `URLSession` delivers that sort of caching for free, though it depends a little upon how your web server is configured. So we often do our own caching, both a small cache in RAM (e.g. `NSCache`) and a bigger cache in persistent storage (e.g. [`.cachesDirectory`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/searchpathdirectory/cachesdirectory)). Libraries like Kingfisher do all this caching for you.

   This doesn't improve the initial fetch, but it dramatically improves performance by avoiding re-fetching something that is already downloaded.
2. **Prefetching**

   You can turn on prefetching, in which, when it’s done requesting data for the visible cells, it will request data for the cells that might soon scroll into view. This means that, assuming it had a chance to catch up, when you scroll, it will show cells for which data has already been prefetched (and while that's going on, it will prefetch data for the cells that might appear next).

   So, again, this doesn’t improve the initial fetch. But if it has a chance to catch up, it *feels* much faster as you scroll through at some modest pace.

   See [`isPrefetchingEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1771771-isprefetchingenabled) and the “Prefetching Collection View Cells and Data” discussion in the `UICollectionView` documentation.
3. **Cancelation**

   When you scroll quickly through a collection view, you want to make sure to cancel requests for cells that are no longer visible. E.g., if you scroll quickly so that you’re looking at cells 100-119, you really don’t want to get backlogged waiting for images for cells 0-99 which aren’t visible any more.

   This is why you really want to use the `URLSession`-based approaches, where you can save weak reference to the running `URLSessionTask` and cancel it when the cell is reused. Or if using Kingfisher, we would `cancelDownloadTask` for the `UIImageView`.
4. **Downloading appropriately sized assets**

   If possible, download appropriately sized assets. For example, let’s say the images are 2,000 × 2,000 pixels. But let’s say you’re on a 3× retina device whose image view is 100 × 100 points. That means that you should download a 300 × 300 pixel image (360kb of data, probably compressed down to less than 50-100kb) rather than the 2,000 × 2,000 asset (16mb of data, even compressed it's likely to be over 1mb). Obviously, implicit in this is that you’re also downloading reasonably compressed assets.

   Admittedly, having assets ready on the server of different sizes is a non-trivial exercise, if you haven’t already implemented this feature, but it's common for well designed web services to (a) prepare assets of different sizes; and (b) offer API to download whichever size the client app needs.

   If downloading large assets to be shown in small collection view cells, this can have a huge impact in actual performance.
5. **Compression**

   Probably needless to say (because it's so common), but make sure the assets transmitted by the server are sufficiently compressed. E.g. a JPEG with compression quality of 70-80% look pretty good, but are significantly smaller than the uncompressed asset. PNG offers compression, too, but doesn't generally offer sizes comparable to JPEGs (because, amongst other things, it’s a lossless compression).

   Bottom line, make sure your assets on the server are reasonably compressed, drawing some balance between quality and size. IMHO, some services go way too far in compressing assets, seriously degrading image quality (I'm talking to you, Facebook), but choose what is a reasonable balance for your application.

So, I second other recommendations for libraries like Kingfisher. It simplifies your client code and delivers on issue #1, caching, automatically. But issues 2 and 3, prefetching and cancelation, will require a little work on your part, but it’s quite simple. And issue #4 (and #5) can have the most dramatic impact (if you don't already have appropriately sized assets), but you’re at the mercy of your web service.

Answer (score 0):

Both are the same as they are variations for a background thread , you better use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) which encapsulates  your logic in a cached and 1 load of the image at any time given that this would occur when user scrolls back and forth before image loads

Comment: does 2nd approach download image in concurrent mode ?

Comment: both download concurrently

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Async Approach

```
let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/image.png")
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

---

```
import KingfisherSwiftUI

var body: some View {
    KFImage(URL(string: "https://example.com/image.png")!)
}
```

you can use https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher library